# Puppet exec - fails to execute command as user

Tags: command, exec, puppet

Writing some classes for cassandra, one of them is to align clustering settings using puppet exec etc. After changing topology strategy, cassandra should rebuild keyspace - this is where puppet comes.
The issue is, while first two are correctly executed under "user", third command is executed in context of root (or w/e). I've checked w/wo notify option and few other compilations, whitout success - any ideas why it might fail??

```
class ogone_cassandra::alter_keyspace () {
# lint:ignore:140chars
  exec {
    'system_auth':
    path     => '/usr/bin',
    provider => shell,
    user     => 'someuser',
    group    => 'cassandra',
    command  => "cqlsh --ssl -u someuser -p $PSW --execute \"ALTER KEYSPACE system_auth WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'par1' : 2, 'par2' : 2, 'ams1' : 1};\"",
    unless   => "nodetool --ssl -u someuser -pw $PSW describecluster | grep -e 'system_auth -> Replication class: NetworkTopologyStrategy' 2>/dev/null",
    require  => Exec['::cassandra::schema connection test'],
    notify   => Exec['repairkeyspace'],
    }
  exec {
    'system_distributed':
    path     => '/usr/bin',
    provider => shell,
    user     => 'someuser',
    group    => 'cassandra',
    command  => "cqlsh --ssl -u someuser -p $PSW --execute \"ALTER KEYSPACE system_distributed WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'par1' : 2, 'par2' : 2, 'ams1' : 1};\"",
    unless   => "nodetool --ssl -u someuser -pw $PSW describecluster | grep -e 'system_distributed -> Replication class: NetworkTopologyStrategy' 2>/dev/null",
    require  => Exec['::cassandra::schema connection test'],
    notify   => Exec['repairkeyspace'],
    }
# lint:endignore
  exec {
    'repairkeyspace':
    path        => '/usr/bin',
    provider    => shell,
    user        => 'someuser',
    group       => 'cassandra',
    command     => 'nodetool --ssl -u someuser -pw $PSW repair --full',
    refreshonly => true,
    }
  }
```

Comment: unless you actually have a user name `$USER` (which sounds like a bad idea) i would expect all commands to be ran as root with an error message like "Error: Could not execute posix command: Invalid user: $USER".  also try running in debug to see if anything elses comes out

Comment: username is particulary defined in final script, just used above notation to avoid providing real credentials here.

Comment: ack, of the top of my head dose nodetool have SUID? (it dosn't by default) otherwise id need more info e.g. debug log

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you're using the `shell` provider?  I don't know why that would cause an issue such as you describe, but it's surprising because you don't appear to be using any shell features in your commands.

Comment: @balder - it doesnt - moreover previous commands are executed correctly :<

Comment: @JohnBollinger Those commands are simply changing the default kespaces within cassandra, while it could be done by some create resoruce, or other option - this is the simplest one basically - other as well may harm authkeyspace which is crucial in this case...

Comment: Not at all what I asked, @altheron_crust.  I'm inquiring about the reason for using `provider    => shell`, as opposed to the default provider (probably `posix`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger true, its without particular reason... case that default one neither works...

Comment: The reason for my inquiry was that if the `posix` provider is a viable option for you, then it is worth trying its option to provide the command and its arguments as an array instead of a string.  That does not work with the `shell` provider.  `provider => 'posix', command => ['nodetool', '--ssl', '-u', 'someuser', '-pw', $PSW, 'repair', '--full']`.  But in retrospect, although that's safer, I don't see why it would make a difference when the first two Execs work normally.

Comment: But are you sure the other two Execs *do* work normally?  For those, the `nodetool` commands are in `unless` properties, not the main command.  Is it possible that you're having the same issue with those `nodetool` commands, but not recognizing it?  If they exit with nonzero status then they will not prevent the main commands from running, even if the *reason* for that exit status is different from what you expect.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry for no answer for long time. In the meantime I've debbuged it and found out, that indeed nodetool command is falling - which haven't seen because of such construction I did. After I examined nodetool itself, it turned out that ntool script is trying to use some variables and paths, that are just not correct for such user. Solved problem using bash sudo -s. Thanks for your effort.